# Emacs indentation wrong

Tags: python, emacs

By default emacs indents like this (python code):

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx = '123' \
                          |<- curret here
```

How to make it indent only 4 additional spaces? Couldn't find it on the internet.

Comment: Do you have an example of some code? `xxx = '123'` then what?

Comment: Also see the [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id19). It seems like Emacs is "correct" in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure how to modify the behavior, but I'd say it's doing something reasonable already.  You shouldn't use backslash continuation, BTW. Write it like `long_var_name = ('123'\n'456')`, where `\n` is actually a newline, not "backslash n".  Use parens (and other brackets) to continue long expressions, not backslash.  The reason is that sometimes you accidentally get a space after the backslash, which leads to confusing bugs.